# How to display information different to the DB value

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, I know it sounds wieird but here's the thing:
In a DB column there are numeric values (1, 2, 3) instead of text. What I need is to show other values instead of the numbers eg: instead of "1", show "Apple".

I'm using PHP MySQL.

I'm totally new here, so your help will be very useful.

Comment: You could use if else statements here, can't you? Please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: `$x=array(1=>'apple');` ... `echo $x[$row[1]]` ..

Comment: Are you trying to do these replacements in PHP code or in the actual MySQL SELECT query?

Comment: In PHP code. The "original request" is this: `<?php echo $row_Get1CTO['ORDORGANO']; ?>` That's of course what Dreamweaver writes by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a conditional

```
<?php
    if($val==1){
        echo 'Apple';
    }elseif($val==2){
        echo 'Pear';
    }
?>
```